# i am trying send email using emailjs in my firebase cloud function but email is not getting send

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-functions

code is compiled successfully and not getting any runtime error  but email is not getting send , please guide me  if this email service in not for server side then which one i should use ..?

```
const functions =require("firebase-functions")
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cron = require('node-cron');
const emailjs =require("@emailjs/browser")
require("dotenv").config();

admin.initializeApp();

exports.printUser=functions.https.onRequest(async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        // Fetch the list of users from Firebase, assuming you have a 'users' collection
        const usersSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('vendors').get();
        const tempArray=[];
       usersSnapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=>
       {
           if(doc.data().lastPromoAdded)
           {
            tempArray.push(doc.data().email)
           }
       })
        // Loop through each user and send an email
        usersSnapshot.forEach((userDoc) => {
          const userData = userDoc.data();
          const userEmail = userData.email;
          if(userData.lastPromoAdded!==undefined){}
  
          
        });
        emailjs
        .send(
          process.env.EMAIL_JS_MY_EMAIL_S_ID,
          process.env.EMAIL_JS_MY_EMAIL_T_ID,
          {
            user_name: "iftekhar",
            message: "hello user by iftekhar",
            user_email: "iftekhar3@gmail.com",
          },
          process.env.EMAIL_JS_MY_EMAIL_PB_KEY
        )
        .then(
          (result) => {
            return res.send(result.text)
          },
          (error) => {
              return res.send(error.text)
          }
        );

        return res.json({data:tempArray});
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending emails:', error);
        return null;
      }
})
```

here is my code
not receiving email, neither receiving nor getting any error